# How can I print an FQL query from JavaScript as a string (e.g. to test it in the Fauna shell)?

Tags: faunadb

FQL queries are constructed in JS as objects. How can I print one of these objects as a string query, for debugging purposes? For example:

```js
q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection("Patterns"), req.params.id))
```

I want to know the FQL string this makes, such as:

```
Get(Ref(Collection("Patterns"), "300223720476116480"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toFQL` method for the `Expr` class.

```js
const expr = q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection("Patterns"), "1234"))

console.log(expr.toFQL())
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that this method is not exposed in the type declaration for Expr, so I didn't notice it.